# Convert a Vcl::Controls::TCaption aka (System::UnicodeString) to a const char *

Tags: c++, c++builder, tmemo

I'm currently using C++Builder to create an application that copies text to the user's clipboard. I've placed a `TMemo` control and I want to contain that in a `const char *` variable as seen in the code below:

```
const char* output = TMemo1->Text;
```

When I compile the program it throws the error

> no viable conversion from 'Vcl::Controls::TCaption' (aka 'System::UnicodeString') to 'const char *'

Here's the code that copies text to the clipboard:

```
const char* output = TMemo1->Text; // Error here
const size_t len = strlen(output) + 1;
HGLOBAL hMem =  GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output, len);
GlobalUnlock(hMem);
OpenClipboard(0);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
CloseClipboard();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Text` property returns a `UnicodeString` object, not a `const char*` pointer. And there is no implicit conversion from `UnicodeString` to `const char*` (nor do you want one).  So you would have to convert the data manually, such as with [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) (or equivalent), eg:

```cpp
UnicodeString text = TMemo1->Text;
const size_t len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, text.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
if (hMem)
{
    char *output = (char*) GlobalLock(hMem);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, text.c_str(), -1, output, len, NULL, NULL);
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    if (OpenClipboard(0))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        if (SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem))
            hMem = NULL;
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    if (hMem)
        GlobalFree(hMem);
}
```

Alternatively, you can save the `TMemo`'s text to an `AnsiString` and let the RTL handle the conversion for you, eg:

```cpp
AnsiString output = TMemo1->Text; // <-- automatic conversion from UTF-16 to ANSI
const size_t len = (output.Length() + 1) * sizeof(System::AnsiChar);
HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
if (hMem)
{
    memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output.c_str(), len);
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    if (OpenClipboard(0))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        if (SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem))
            hMem = NULL;
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    if (hMem)
        GlobalFree(hMem);
}
```

However, since you are dealing with Unicode text, you should be using the `CF_UNICODETEXT` format instead of `CF_TEXT`.  That way, you don't need to convert the `UnicodeString` data at all, you can just store it as-is (if anybody requests `CF_TEXT` from the clipboard afterwards, [the clipboard itself will convert the text for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats#synthesized-clipboard-formats)), eg:

```cpp
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp> // for ByteLength()

UnicodeString output = TMemo1->Text;
const size_t len = ByteLength(output) + sizeof(System::WideChar);
HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
if (hMem)
{
    memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output.c_str(), len);
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    if (OpenClipboard(0))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        if (SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hMem))
            hMem = NULL;
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    if (hMem)
        GlobalFree(hMem);
}
```

That being said, you are making things harder for yourself then you need to.  The VCL has a [`TClipboard`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Clipbrd.TClipboard) class that handles all of these details for you, eg:

```
#include <Vcl.Clipbrd.hpp>

Clipboard()->AsText = TMemo1->Text;
```